# Uncaught ReferenceError: Main is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a bit of trouble calling a function from one Javascript file from another.

the call my search.js file is using is

```
Main.UserRoleTeam({
    teamdropdown: $("#Team"),
    teamroledropdown: $("#TeamRole"),
    memoryload: true,
    load: function (options) {
    }
});
```

The other file is Main.js

```
function UserRoleTeam(options) {
    ...
}
```

In dev, this works in test, it does not.

The folder \ file structure is exactly the same and I have checked all this.

I have also used a diff tool to look at solution \ folder \ file differences and there is nothing.

In my aspx page the files are being called like so.

```
<script src="../Static/Search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Static/Main.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have check the other answers on here, and tried various solutions, most of which state that the order of the calling files should be as above.

================================================

Edit 1

looking at the page source, the values I should be expecting back are in the sourcecode,

```
<div class="user text-right">
    <b>User:</b><span id="UserName">adrian wright</span><br />
    <b>Team:</b><select name="Team" id="Team">
        <option value="4" data-roles="Agent|AGENT">CPS</option>
        <option value="5" data-roles="Manufacturer|MANUFACTURER">TEJ</option>
        <option value="3" data-roles="Supplier|SUPPLIER">SHA</option>
    </select>
   <br />
   <b>Role:</b><select name="TeamRole" id="TeamRole">
   </select>
</div>
```

But the selection list isnt populating, with the value.

again, code is exactly the same as in dev as in test but dev working, test is not.

Comment: The other of the files should be reversed...Functions in Main.js aren't available to Search.js until they're loaded...

Comment: In addition to @rnevius's point above, what you've shown for Main.js will not create a `Main` object, just a function called `UserRoleTeam`.

Comment: but why does this work in a dev environment, then not a test environment?

i will switch the calling of it around, and see how that works but im puzzled as to why one works, one doesnt

Comment: changing the order broke it in dev, and kept it the same in test.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is currently `window.UserRoleTeam`, not `window.Main.UserRoleTeam`.

To correct this change your function declaration to:

```
var Main = Main || {};
Main.UserRoleTeam(options) {
    ...
}
```

Secondly make sure this is declared before being called. To do this you will need to reorder your javascript references:

```
<script src="../Static/Main.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Static/Search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm not sure why it works locally, but it shouldn't be, unless you have other code in dev supporting this.

---

FYI - Adding functions into a file called `Main.js` doesn't make the function exist under a `Main` object.

Comment: still get the same error, and the code, on each dev and test server are \ were the same which is why i am flummoxed

Comment: using your solution i get the error i get now is "Uncaught TypeError: Main.UserRoleCompany is not a function"

Comment: @SimonPrice Looks like you will need to implement a similar change for `UserRoleCompany` then

Comment: @SimonPrice FYI - Adding functions into a file called `Main.js` doesn't make the function exist under a `Main` object.